# Extracting bucket and key from S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

In order to delete a file from S3 with given a file url like `https://user-files.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234-5678/image.png`, is there a way to delete the file using the url?

If bucket and key are a must, is there an **official way** to extract them from the URL?

I dont want to assume anything about the url because if in the future ill use `forcePathStyle` the url will look differently (it will look like `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/user-files/1234-5678/image.png`, and in this case the bucket name doesnt resides in the hostname).
So trying to avoid string manipulations (e.g `url.hostname.split(".")[0]`).

Comment: just don't use forcePathStyle. IIRC Amazon doesn't want you to use this style anyway, because it can't direct certain buckets to certain IP addresses.

Comment: Why do you have an HTTP URL in the first place, rather than a bucket/key pair?